# Converting Redux to React Context API + useReducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, middleware

I am in the process of converting my redux structure to Context API combined with `useReducer`. Everything is working as intended, however I had a web socket middleware, which I bound to redux with `applyMiddleware` and `redux-thunk`. Really confused on how can I bind the middleware to work with my structure.

*MyContext.js*

```
import { createContext } from 'react'

export const initialState = {
    values : {}
}

export const Context = createContext(initialState)
```

*MyProvider.js*

```
import { monitoring } from './reducers/monitoring'
import { Context, initialState } from './monitoringContext'
import { useReducerWithMiddleware } from './reducerMiddleware'

export const MonitoringProvider = ({ middleware, children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducerWithMiddleware(monitoring, initialState, middleware)

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}
```

*useReducerMiddleware.js* (implemented `redux-thunk` alike structure here)

```
import { useReducer } from "react";

export const useReducerWithMiddleware = (reducer, initialState, middleware) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const thunkDispatch = action => {
    if (typeof action === "function") {
      return action(thunkDispatch, state)
    }

    return middleware(dispatch(action))
  };
    return [state, thunkDispatch];
};
```

*I bind the provider like this*:

```
  <MonitoringProvider middleware={reducerSocketMiddleware}> // This is the socketFunction provided below
      <Layout /> // This is a component that handles all the routing
   </MonitoringProvider>
```

And I want to bind the  `socketFunction` middleware. Right now, none of the actions dispatched are going through this middleware.

*socketFunction*:

```
const socketFunction = store => next => action => {
    debugger // No visits to this debugger
    if (action.type === SOCKET_ACTION_TYPES.CONNECT_SOCKET_IO) {
        /* Connect socket */
    } else if (action.type === SOCKET_ACTION_TYPES.DISCONNECT_SOCKET_IO) {
        if (socket) socket.close(CLOSE_SIG)
    } else {
        return next(action)
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing that conversion might not be a good idea - Context is technically not very well suited for state value propagation. (React-Redux 6 used it and moved away with version 7 due to performance problems.) You might want to read https://dev.to/javmurillo/react-context-all-in-one-54ck and the other links going off that post. I'd recommend looking into modern Redux, which is only a fourth of the "vanilla-style" Redux you are currently using: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux

Comment: Thanks for the insight, indeed that was not a good idea. I was just testing this new approach because I came across some performance issues with redux. Context was way worse though. Useful links!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not calling the middleware appropriately.

```
middleware(state)(dispatch)(action)
```

solved the problem.